# iOS 11 SearchDisplayController shows black status bar

Tags: ios, ios11, searchdisplaycontroller

I know SearchDisplayController is deprecated, but Storyboard still supports it, and it is an easy way to present tableViewController on top of your view controller. I have been using it, and I would still prefer to use that. And in iOS 11, when I run my app, the status bar of the SearchDisplayController. after the search bar is focused, is pitch BLACK. Does anyone know how to solve this bug? Also if you realize, the margins of the searcher is off. I am using the default iOS 11 searchbar. Below is attached screenshot:

[image: look at the empty black status bar space]

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to set the extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars property to true?

```
searchDisplayController.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not the best solution actually, but It works to change status bar color.

```
if let statusBar = UIApplication.shared.value(forKeyPath: "statusBarWindow.statusBar") as? UIView {
    statusBar.backgroundColor = //YOUR COLOR HERE
  }
```

Keep in mind this will affect the whole app. If you need to change some views only then save the previous color to restore it.

Regards.